TypeError: this.getOptions is not a function - ERROR in ./node_modules/font-awesome-sass-loader/font-awesome-sass.config.js
Error while building React App
TypeError: this.getOptions is not a function - ERROR in ./node_modules/font-awesome-sass-loader/font-awesome-sass.config.js

Package.json
dependencies : {
       "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "font-awesome-sass-loader": "^1.0.5",
   ...
  },

webpack.config.js
module : {
Rules: [{
test: /.(s(a|c)ss)$/,
use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
},
....
]
}

What's the version of your webpack?
